# JQuery Template Engine Half-Works in Chrome,Safari,Firefox

Tags: jquery, debugging, file-upload, cross-browser, filepath

Simple question, but probavbly complicated answer.  I am using the BluImp JQuery File-Uploader.  I have customized the templates so that a file with a really long name won't mess up the look of my webpage.  Here is an example of the code I use to do that.

```
    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    {% if (file.name.length > 16) file.name = file.name.substring(0, 16) + "..."; %}
      <tr class="template-upload fade">
          <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
          {% if (file.error) { %}
              <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
          {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
              <td>
                  <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
              </td>
              <td>{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                  <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                      <i class="icon-upload icon-black"></i>
                      <span>Start</span>
                  </button>
              {% } %}</td>
          {% } else { %}
              <td colspan="2"></td>
          {% } %}
          <td>{% if (!i) { %}
              <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                  <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-black"></i>
                  <span>Cancel</span>
              </button>
          {% } %}</td>
      </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    {% if (file.name.length > 16) file.name = file.name.substring(0, 16) + "..."; %}
      <tr class="template-download fade">
          {% if (file.error) { %}
              <td></td>
              <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
              <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
              <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span>{%=file.error%}</td>
          {% } else { %}
              <td class="name">
                {%=file.name%}
              </td>
              <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
              <td colspan="1"></td>
          {% } %}
          <td width="130px;">
              <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                  <i class="icon-trash icon-black"></i>
                  <span>Delete</span>
              </button>
              <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
          </td>
      </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>
```

The file.name formatting always works in IE.  In all other browsers, only the download template works.  I.E. The file name is only trimmed AFTER the file has been uploaded.  So, how to I get the file name to be trimmed down BEFORE upload in other browsers?

Comment: Ew! I'd help, but I don't wanna get templating script on my hands!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to trim it manually, such as the following to Windows paths:

```
.replace(/[^\\]+\\/g,"");
```